# Is it a bug or what?

Tags: support, status-completed, mathjax

I remember I didn't have this problem before, but now I refreshed the page trice but the LaTeX part isn't shown properly.

[image]

Comment: It's a global problem, see [Where's the LaTeX love gone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125478/167500).

Comment: If have always wondered why so many sites like to introduce dependencies by not hosting the JavaScripts they use locally.

Comment: @uli: *speed!* When you can load a page without re-downloading the script because it's already cached by your browser, or when downloading it pulls it from a server closer to your location, then under normal conditions the page will load faster, and you'll have a more pleasant experience on the site. The SE devs spend a ridiculous amount of time working to shave off a few milliseconds here and there - it all adds up...

Comment: At the price of importing other peoples downtimes...  If SE would keep a copy for all its sites, the effect would be the same, without the dependency. What if they go out of service, or change the version an break your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax's CDN is having... *issues*.

Nothing we can do on our end, should be resolved soon.

Update: appears to be up now. Devs have added potential for a work-around if it happens again.